# Можно ли отсортировать выборку по двум полям 'date' и 'time' сразу?

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно отсортировать выборку по дате и времени (двум полям) одновременно, т.е. выводить сначала более новые записи. Можно ли это сделать посредством SQL?

Comment: можно. соберите в дату-время и оссортируйте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, через запятую перечисляете парметры сортировки.

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `dateField` DESC, `timeField` DESC
```

А лучше храните одно поле типа DATETIME, в котормо сразу и дата и время